# I am looking for a method that can take string and format it to ISO 8601 timestamp

Tags: datetime, go, iso8601

I am trying to take a string and convert that string into **ISO8601** timestamp format using Go.

I read a few StackOverflow posts and tried them, none of them worked for me. I might be doing it wrong?

My datetime string is something like

```golang
date := "8/16/2019 8:01:35 PM"
```

```golang
func main() {
    date := "8/16/2019 8:01:35 PM"
    t, _ := time.Parse("6/16/2019 3:07:53 PM", date)
    fmt.Println(t) // getting 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

I am expecting to get a parsed DateTime value which is something like `2019-8-16T20:01:35` from the above code and then convert it to **ISO8601** format, like `2019-8-16T20:01:35.000Z` as an end result.

Comment: First, read the documentation: [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)

Comment: `"6/16/2019 3:07:53 PM"` is not a valid format string. A format string must format the canonical date, as clearly described in the docs.

Comment: Also, never ignore errors. `time.Parse` returns an error and in your case it would have told you: parsing time "8/16/2019 8:01:35 PM" as "6/16/2019 3:07:53 PM": cannot parse "8/16/2019 8:01:35 PM" as "6/"

Comment: Thanks all. I was just getting started with go and I did not understand much about how to look up for details in the documentation, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

the numbers on the example date can only be as follows

month: 1, 01, jan, January
day: 2, 02
year: 06, 2006,
hour: 3, 03, or for 24hour 15,
minutes: 4, 04
seconds 5, 05, 05.000, 05.000000
timezone -0700, MST

```
input := "8/16/2019 8:01:35 PM"
layout := "1/02/2006 3:04:05 PM"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, input)
fmt.Println(t, err)
fmt.Println(t.Format("1/02/2006 3:04:05 PM")) // 31-Aug-2017
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dQuN8n30HgM)

for more details [checkout](https://programming.guide/go/format-parse-string-time-date-example.html)